# Using relative layout with adjustment and alignment issues

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

```
Android Studio 1.2
```

Hello,

I have this Relative layout that will be a row in a listview. So I would like to keep with relative layout for performance as there will be a lot of scrolling.

The problem, I can't seem to get the alignment correct. This is what I have:
[image]

And below is the wireframe that I have designed and what the above should look like:

[image]

The date and time is ok. First, Is just the alignment of the `Correct 20` and `Incorrect 18` They should be aligned to the right. Second, the `thumbs up` and `thumbs down` Doesn't how much I resize them, I can't get them aligned like the wireframe.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Just a quick question, the design looks very boring, any suggestions to make it look a bit more sexy ;)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightLarge"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="16 Mar 2015"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="22:15"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCorrectTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Correct 20"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvIncorrect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Incorrect 18"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivArrow"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next_item"
        android:scaleType="center"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivCorrect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivArrow"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_good"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivIncorrect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivArrow"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_bad"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use LinearLayout with weights for TextViews. Something like this:

[image: Layout]

Or you can try [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) or [Support GridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayout.html).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:rowCount="2"
    app:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        app:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:text="16 Mar 2015"/>

    <TextView
        app:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:text="22:15"/>

    <TextView
        app:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:text="Correct 20"/>

    <TextView
        app:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:text="Incorrect 18"/>

    <ImageView
        app:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:src="..." />
    <ImageView
        app:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:src="..."/>

    <ImageView
        app:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        app:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:src="..."/>

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

You may need additional margins here or still can try weights. I don't think weights will cause performance issue as long you use `ViewHolder` pattern.

Comment: I was really trying to do this without nested linear layouts for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Change main Relative layout to LinearLayout and inside the LinearLayout use Relative Layout as below

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightLarge"
    android:padding="8dp">
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightLarge"
    android:padding="8dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="16 Mar 2015"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="22:15"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCorrectTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Correct 20"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvIncorrect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Incorrect 18"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivArrow"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next_item"
        android:scaleType="center"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivCorrect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivArrow"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_good"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivIncorrect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivArrow"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_bad"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Still didn't align the textview correct and incorrect. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a GridLayout or a TableLayout there, as your activity really needs to organize that data in this way.